# ionic Bind maxlength dynamically ionic2

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, ionic2

My  requirement  is to  bind  `maxlength` to `ion-input`. I  have tried using  interpolation concept  to  bind.

My html

```
 <ion-list >
    <ion-item *ngFor=" let a of arr_label">
      <ion-label floating>{{a.lblname}}</ion-label>
      <ion-input maxlength={{a.maxlent}}   [(ngModel)]="a.Val" type="text"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

.ts

```
arr_label:any[]=[];
this.arr_label.push({maxlent:10});
```

Is there  something  am  missing... any  help  is  quite  appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind to attributes in 3 different ways

Bind directly to it, if it's a native attribute:

```html
<ion-input [maxlength]="a.maxlent" [(ngModel)]="a.Val" type="text"></ion-input>
```

Bind to it with `attr` prefix - works on custom and native attributes:

```html
<ion-input [attr.maxlength]="a.maxlent" [(ngModel)]="a.Val" type="text"></ion-input>
```

Or just set its value to the interpolated string value of the variable:

```html
<ion-input maxlength="{{a.maxlent}}" [(ngModel)]="a.Val" type="text"></ion-input>
```

Comment: Tried all three.Its  not  working..Throwing exception  for 1&3--Invalid integer literal when parsing null...  for  Second  one  --no  exception,no binding..

Comment: even  if  i  hard-code any value  instead  of  iterated  value..Its  showing  same  error.--Invalid integer literal when parsing a.maxlent

Comment: I just tested it in a plunker - the Ionic `ion-input` wrapper seems to ignore that attribute.

Comment: Any  other  solution/Ideas @rinukkusu

Answer (score 0):

Like you can see in [Angular 2 docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#binding-targets)  you can achieve what you're looking for by using the attribute binding like this:

```
<ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="myInput" [attr.maxlength]="maxLength"></ion-input>
```

Please take a look at the code in this [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aWQwdy?p=preview).

Comment: `<ion-input type="number" value="" [(ngModel)]="Amount" maxlength="10" ></ion-input>`

With text type = "number" it is not working.

Can you give me a solution?